# what is the best way to upgrade web.config?

Tags: .net, merge, web-config, upgrade

I have a web application to which I wrote an upgrade utility.
It rewrites the binaries and updates the web.config (with new sections, changed attributes, elements etc..).

I want to preserve my client's custom configuration, but I want to add the necessary changes like new sections or elements inside sections.

What are the best practices for this scenario?

Comment: Web.Config transformations: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465318%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Would it not be easier to split out your web.config into a number of distinct sections and use the configsource attribute to point it to an external file.

```
<compilation configSource="configs\system.web.compilation.config" />
```

That way if you add new sections to the main web.config just has a number of pointers to external files for all aspects of the application.

It means that you can split out the stuff that client specific to the particular files. In our case we split out the config for DEV/UAT/PROD and use nAnt to overwrite the relevant files depending on the environment witht the appropriate ones for the environment.